# How to get more info for thread in java which blocks my app

Tags: multithreading, debian

Thread[TP-Processor2,5,main] - This is the thread which is blocking my java app. I use tomcat server and Debian linux. The thread is part of my java app! I want to investigate the thread. How I can get more info about this thread in Debian?

What does it mean TP-Processor2,5,main ?

I have this error:

> 11-11-2015 12:33:23,864 ERROR
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.logRuntimeException:1521 -
>   org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: After 1 minute the Pagemap
>   null is still locked by: Thread[TP-Processor2,5,main], giving up
>   trying to get the page for path: 3:log_out_link
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.request.InvalidUrlException:
>   org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: After 1 minute the Pagemap
>   null is still locked by: Thread[TP-Processor2,5,main], giving up
>   trying to get the page for path: 3:log_out_link   at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycleProcessor.resolve(WebRequestCycleProcessor.java:262)
>     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1310)  at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)  at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:312)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
>     at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
>     at
>   org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) Caused by:
>   org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: After 1 minute the Pagemap
>   null is still locked by: Thread[TP-Processor2,5,main], giving up
>   trying to get the page for path: 3:log_out_link   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3116)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3573)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4113)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2812)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5339)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:91)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1354)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:38)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.enlistInCurrentTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.doJoinTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:374)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:332)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.find(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.velti.smsoffice.admin.AdministrationBean.saveDomain(AdministrationBean.java:115)
>     at
>   com.velti.smsoffice.admin.AdministrationBean$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3af2a32f.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:692)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)
>     at
>   com.velti.smsoffice.admin.AdministrationBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4cdf5a11.saveDomain()
>     at
>   com.velti.smsoffice.ui.users.SortedUsersProvider.saveDomain(SortedUsersProvider.java:175)
>     at com.velti.smsoffice.ui.users.Users.persistItem(Users.java:409)   at
>   com.velti.smsoffice.ui.MyFormPanel$1.onSubmit(MyFormPanel.java:57)    at
>   org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton$1.onSubmit(AjaxButton.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.BehaviorRequestTarget.processEvents(BehaviorRequestTarget.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
>     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)  ...
>   19 more

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'TP-Processor2' is the current thread. This call is taking more than 1 minute to execute hence the current timeouts.

You can use Jconsole to view more about the thread.

Comment: what means "5" and "main"

Comment: Also in jconsole i dont find thread named TP-Processor2. Where is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the names are in your server but it will be a webcontainer thread.

(Usually for tomcat its http-8080-1).

Definitely this thread more time for execution - I can see some database activities.

Check this thread as well:

[Increase the lock time for "After 1 minute the Pagemap null is still locked" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353765/increase-the-lock-time-for-after-1-minute-the-pagemap-null-is-still-locked-exc)